# what is the legal age to buy tobacco products in Greece?

Tags: greece, smoking

i am a smoker in canada, but i’m 18. so i cannot bring cigsrettes with me to greece. So i’m wondering if i can buy smokes/cigarettes in Greece when i’m there. because i can’t last 10 whole days without a smoke

Comment: I am curious: why do you say you cannot bring them with you?

Comment: @RichardBeasley Customs?  I don't know what age has to do with it.

Comment: @gerrit I always have cigarettes on me when flying so I don't understand that either.

Comment: The legal age in the European Union is 18. The question is being asked because in American States/Provences different age limits exist.

Answer (score 4):

I used to buy cigarettes for my father when I was little.

I have never heard of anyone being prosecuted for such a thing in Greece but some shop owners might refuse if the buyer is a kid. Since you're not a kid though, it is very unlikely that you will have any kind of problem buying cigarettes.

Answer (score 2):

With the passage of [Law 3730/2008](https://www.e-nomothesia.gr/kat-anilikoi/n-3730-2008.html) - Government Gazette 262 / A / 23-12-2008 the protection of minors from tobacco and alcoholic beverages was introduced. According to this law:

- Minors are those who have not reached the age of eighteen
- The sale of tobacco products to minors and the sale of tobacco from minors is prohibited
- Minors are prohibited from entering and staying (...) in leisure centers and bars, and minors are prohibited also from the consumption of alcoholic beverages in all public centers, except for private events.

By the [Law 4633/2019](https://www.e-nomothesia.gr/kat-ygeia/nomos-4633-2019-phek-161a-16-10-2019.html) Government Gazette 161 / A / 16-10-2019… regulations on tobacco products…, smoking and electronic cigarettes are prohibited in all public indoor areas with no exceptions and extends to outdoor areas of sports, entertainment, and gathering of minors.